# helm provide values file from variable

Tags: parameter-passing, kubernetes-helm

I'm having an ci/cd pipeline with has a yaml file, containing secrets in memory. I don't want to store the file on drive, since I have not guarantee that the file will be cleaned or is safe on the drive.

I would like to install a helm chart using `helm install`. Normally I would just provide the file using `-f filename.yaml`. But as I said, I don't have the file stored on the drive. Is there any alternative to pass a whole yaml file as string to a helm install command?

Comment: You can use `--set` and pass the value as an argument. Take a look at the help of `helm install`.

Answer (score 2):

To inline `values.yaml` in your command line, you can use the following:

```
helm install <chart-name> -f - <<EOF
<your-inlined-values-yaml>
EOF
```

For example:

```
helm install --name my-release hazelcast/hazelcast -f - <<EOF
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
EOF
```